# SQL Server Reporting Services HTML Error 500.24

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been using SQL Server Reporting Services on many servers but on this particular one when I try to open the url to create subscriptions I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode

Any advise would be greatly appreciated, please advise if more information is required

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to simply switch your Managed Pipeline mode from Integrated to Classic in IIS.

The steps would be as follows.

1. Start the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager from the Start menu on the Windows machine.
2. Click on Application Pools from the left menu and select the application you are working on from the middle table.
3. Right-cick to bring up the "Set Application Defaults" menu.
4. Change Managed Pipeline Mode from "Integrated" to "Classic" and press OK.

You will then see the Managed Pipeline column for that item change from Integrated to Classic.

This should at least get rid of the error message, without diagnosing the cause (which would require a lot more information).

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, I had to create the virtual directory for Report manager URL.Once I added the virtual directory name and clicked apply, the report manager opened in IE.